# mod_rewrite not working for php files

Tags: ubuntu, mod-rewrite, apache2

I use `Ubuntu server`. I configured `apache2` `VirtualHost` like:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

In `.htaccess` file I wrote:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php
RewriteRule ^test$ test.html
```

But as a result it works for:

```
domain.com/test
```

and does not work for

```
domain.com/about
```

So what I missed or why the `RewriteRule` does not work for `.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used following in my `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
...
</Directory>
```

But it seems `DocumentRoot` is prepended to `Directory` when looking for `Directory`.

It started to work after I changed the `config` as following:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory />
...
</Directory>
```